# Cannot connect to MySQL running in Docker from host machine

Tags: macos, docker

I have multiple MySQL servers running in separate docker containers. I'm not able to connect to either one from the host machine.

```
$ mysql -h172.17.0.2 -uroot -pPASSWORD
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2' (60)
```

IP address from docker inspect:

```
$ docker inspect local2 | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

And ports exposed (but not mapped):

```
$ docker inspect local2 | grep -B1 3306
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {},
                "33060/tcp": {}
--
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": null,
                "33060/tcp": null
```

The docker container was created (and recreated) with

```
docker run --name local -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=PASSWORD -d mysql:8.0.21
```

And I can connect from another docker client on the network:

```
docker run -it --network bridge --rm mysql mysql -h172.17.0.2 -uroot -pPASSWORD
```

Also if I bash into the container I am able to connect locally with localhost.

I only can't connect from the host machine.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but have you specified `host` while starting new container

Comment: @emotionlessbananas Thank you for chiming in. I updated the question with the docker run comment for the mysql container. I'm not sure what you mean by specifying `host`.

Comment: Have you tried to bind port with `-p 3306:3306` in the `docker run` command ?

Comment: @Philippe that is exactly what I was trying to avoid so I could use the same default port for multiple docker instances (differentiated by IP address).

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I found it's not actually possible to access the Docker instance on a Mac without mapping a port.

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2670#issuecomment-371249949

> You cannot access container IPs directly on mac. You need to use localhost with port forwarding
>
> See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds

:(

I'd be happy to be wrong here..

Comment: This  was I meant with host. I would have added more details

Comment: The Docker-internal IP addresses are essentially useless.  You can't access them from other hosts at all; unless you're on native Linux, you can't access them from outside containers even on the same host; and between containers (on the same Docker-internal network) Docker provides a native DNS system so you can use container names as hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot any problem in your way of accessing the service in the container. I just suspect that the service is not actually ready yet.

Maybe that'll give you an idea to troubleshoot:

```
passwd=pw
id=$(docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="$passwd" --detach mysql)

ip=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' "$id")

printf "listing open ports on %s:\n You might have wait some seconds until they are open\n" "$ip"
nmap "$ip" -p 3306,33060

printf "connecting to %s:\n" "$ip"
mysql --host="$ip" --user="root" --password="$passwd" --protocol=TCP --wait
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I updated the question with more information. I can connect to it from a separate docker instance and using localhost inside the running docker container.  I've also checked the logs. It's definitely running. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=PASSWORD mysql
```